# iOS app crashes when I click Google Sign-In button

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, google-signin

I'm using the Google Sign-In library for iOS, and when I click the Sign-In button the app crashes with the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
 'Your app must support the following URL schemes: <my bundleID>,
 com.googleusercontent.apps.<my client ID>'
```

I inspected the signed version of my app to make sure that those URL schemes are defined, which they are.
I also added 'google' as the identifier for each of the URL schemes because I saw that that's what is done in the sample Google Sign-In app.
This only happens when I build the signed version of my app and do an ad-hoc installation on my phone.
It doesn't happen when running in the simulator through Xcode, or even when running the app for release on the simulator through Xcode.
Does anyone know what to do about this?

Other info that might be useful:
I'm using the Google Sign-In library without cocoapods.
I dragged the library bundle and framework into my project.
Also, I'm using a generic provisioning profile which contains a wildcard in the App ID, and for some reason when I build the signed version of the app the bundle ID of my app gets changed to have the wildcard in it.
i.e. the bundle id gets changed from com.example.app to com.example.*.
Because of this, I added in a third URL scheme which contains the wildcard.

Answer (score 6):

Add the URL scheme:

1. Under Project  -> Info -> URL Types
2. Create new URL types
3. Under URL scheme add your bundle identifier.

This resolves the issue.

Comment: This was the final issue that resolved it for me. The other help sections I read omitted the identifier for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

So i had that problem for a couple of hours and then i did what you can see in the pic.
Just opened anther URL type and in the schemes add the bundle identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I finally figured out the issue.  I'm almost positive the issue was the generic provisioning profile I was using. When I created a provisioning profile that was specific to my app and removed the URL scheme with the wildcard, I no longer had that problem.

Comment: Your answer helped me :)

Comment: I hve same issue, how to add URL scheme with wildcard?

Answer (score 1):

**If you know you have added the right URL scheme to Xcode but it still crashes**, you can change a simulator to iOS version 14, and it works, if you can load it on Android device, and that means your code is good, so it should work on real devices once you publish your app.

**Reminder: this will only work after you add Url scheme to Xcode!**